# SYSTEMINDEX returns paths those do not exist

Tags: windows, powershell

**Environment**
I have windows 10 with two languages installed 
first one is Polish(i use it as main language in the system) second one is English.
I'm able to open directories in the explorer using english and polish paths ie.
`C:\Users\User\Desktop` and `C:\Użytkownicy\User\Pulpit`

**Code**
I'm trying to figure out if it is problem with SYSTEMINDEX or windows at all.
i have folllwing query to the SYSTEMINDEX

`$sql = "SELECT System.ItemFolderPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE System.fileExtension`

later when i terate through query i do the following

`Get-Item $rs.Fields.Item("System.ItemFolderPathDisplay").Value).fullname`

But paths stored in  the `SYSTEMINDEX` are localized ones like `C:\Użytkownicy\User\Pulpit\file.txt`
and `Get-Item` returns an error

`powershell search: Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Użytkownicy\User\Pulpit\file.txt' because it does not exist.`

So i wonder if there is some flag which i can set so Paths will be returned in the non-localized form? Or maybe it is some kind of bug in windows?

Comment: Try `(Get-Item $rs.Fields.Item("System.ItemFolderPathDisplay")).Target`

Comment: Try `Get-Item` with `-Force` switch.